# Class is still active after setting to nothing Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a class without a form in visual basic and it includes a timer which has an interval of 5000ms.

The issue I am having is when I set the class to Nothing, it seems that the class is still active and the timer is still ticking?

Is there a way to completely dispose of the class and end its life?

```
Public Class MyCustomClass

  Public GlobalTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

  Public Sub New()

    GlobalTimer.Interval = 5000
    GlobalTimer.Enabled = True
    GlobalTimer.Start()
    AddHandler GlobalTimer.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimer_Tick

  End Sub

  Public Sub GlobalTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
  EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Tick")
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: also please share the code you used as exmplained in: [mcve] and also try to read [ask]

Comment: could you tell us which class it is? is it your own custom class? if its a custom class we would need to see its code in order to evaluate a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, it is a custom class, why do you need to see the class itself? For reasons, I cannot share the code but it is a simple custom class with a timer created programmatically. I am setting the class variable to Nothing outside of the class itself. @DannyJames

Comment: we can't tell why your not emptying the code if you don't share the function where you empty the class and how it is structured. You don't have to put al the code like I said if you take time to read: [mcve] you will see what you need to share to help us help you

Comment: If you can't share *this exact code* then create a shareable (e.g., strip out any proprietary information, etc.) version that mimics the problem. If you can't mimic the problem, then you need to compare the two classes and see what you're doing differently in each. If you can mimic the problem, then voila, you've created an MCVE which you should share here, which will allow others to assist you.

Comment: Setting a class instance to Nothing doesn't clear everything up. You still need to dispose the instance properly with something like .Dispose() and handle the event to stop your timer. Also, garbage collection is called only when it is needed, not everytime you set something to nothing.

Comment: you'd need a method in the class to do, `GlobalTimer.Dispose()` so then you could do `mycustomclass.dispose`

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that "Setting a class instance to Nothing doesn't clear everything up." 
Given that, here is the updated version of MyCustomClass to achieve the desired behavior. The class now implements IDisposable interface and Dispose() method.

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
    Implements IDisposable

    Public GlobalTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Public Sub New()        
        GlobalTimer.Interval = 1000
        GlobalTimer.Enabled = True
        GlobalTimer.Start()
        AddHandler GlobalTimer.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimer_Tick

    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        GlobalTimer.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GlobalTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Tick")
    End Sub 
End Class
```

In order to make it work you either need to call dispose method MyCustomClass object or use that method within *using* block, instead of setting it to nothing.

```
dim cusClassObj as new MyCustomClass()
    ' perform other tasks here
cusClassObj.Dispose()
```

OR

```
Using cusClassObj As New MyCustomClass()
    ' perform other tasks here
End Using
```